# remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/openstack.dev/devstack.git/' not found

Tags: github, ubuntu-14.04

while downloading open stack kilo from git hub by using a command `git clone https://github.com/openstack.dev/devstack.git -b stable/kilo`It was asking about user name and password.Then i entered my git hub account credentials.but it rises an error saying that `remote: Repository not found.fatal: repository 'https://github.com/openstack.dev/devstack.git/' not found`. can any one please help in solving this?